# Pandas: How to choose plot element colors when using plotly as a backend?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I'm experimenting with [Plotly as a pandas plot backend](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/). I successfuly configured it following [these instructions](https://towardsdev.com/how-to-use-plotly-as-pandas-plotting-backend-123ff5378003), but I'm having trouble to configure my chart element colors.

Here is what I want to do. It works with matplotlib as a backend:

```
df.plot(kind='area', 
        color=['orange', 'lightslategray'],
        backend='matplotlib' )
```

[image: correct chart]

But when I try using ploty, it fails with a strange error:

```
df.plot(kind='area', 
        color=['orange', 'lightslategray'], 
        backend='plotly' )
```

The error:

```
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `color` is 2, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['Dia', 'Alfa', 'Beta'] is 12
```

The plot works if I don't try to set any color:

```
df.plot(kind='area', backend='plotly' )
```

[image: plotly with wrong colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some of the parameters don't have the same meaning depending on your plotting backend. `color` is one of them. When using plotly it tries to choose a dimension that will be used as color. The correct way is to use the `color_discrete_map` parameter:

```
df.plot(kind='area', 
        color_discrete_map={
            'Alfa': 'orange', 
            'Beta': 'lightslategray'}, 
        backend='plotly' )
```

[image: Correctly plot]

Unfortunately it won't be possible to interchange the backend engine.